# how to make a repeating image or pattern in interface builder

Tags: interface-builder, xcode5

I've been playing around with Interface builder in Xcode 5 and can't work out how I would create a repeating image like this area circled in red..

[image]

As I'm a newbie with this.. is a repeating image the best approach for this.. and is this possible in Interface Builder?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than repeating an image I worked out how to draw a gradient in a custom view. This is my drawRect function for my custom view:

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {
    [super drawRect:dirtyRect];

    NSRect        bounds = [self bounds];

    NSGradient* aGradient = [[NSGradient alloc]
                             initWithColorsAndLocations:[NSColor colorWithRed:.980f green:.980f blue:.980f alpha:1.0f], (CGFloat)0.0,
                              [NSColor colorWithRed:.956f green:.956f blue:.956f alpha:1.0f], (CGFloat)0.48,
                              [NSColor colorWithRed:.917f green:.917f blue:.917f alpha:1.0f], (CGFloat)0.49,
                              [NSColor colorWithRed:.937f green:.937f blue:.937f alpha:1.0f], (CGFloat)1.0,
                              nil];

    [aGradient drawInRect:bounds angle:-90.0];

    //disable antialias
    [[NSGraphicsContext currentContext] setShouldAntialias: NO];

    NSBezierPath * path = [NSBezierPath bezierPath];
    [path setLineWidth: 0];

    [path  moveToPoint: (NSPoint) { 0, self.bounds.size.height-1 } ];
    [path lineToPoint: (NSPoint){ self.bounds.size.width ,self.bounds.size.height-1 } ];

    [[NSColor colorWithRed:0.647058824f green:0.647058824f blue:0.647058824f alpha:1.0f] set];
    [path stroke];
}
```